# Active windows in Windows and QWidget::activateWindow()

Tags: windows, qt, window-managers, foreground

The Qt documentation for `QWidget::activateWindow()` states:

> On Windows, if you are calling this
>   when the application is not currently
>   the active one then it will not make
>   it the active window. It will change
>   the color of the taskbar entry to
>   indicate that the window has changed
>   in some way. This is because Microsoft
>   does not allow an application to
>   interrupt what the user is currently
>   doing in another application.

However, Skype appears to defy this rule. If Skype is running but is not the active application, I can launch it from the start menu and it brings the existing instance to the foreground, activates it and grabs input focus.

And how can *I* do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*NOTE: This is specific to how QtSingleApplication works*)

The solution is stupidly simple for my issue. Simply call `AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASF_ANY);` at the beginning of the application, and the original process will thus be allowed to bring itself to the foreground by use of `SetForegroundWindow()`. No strange hacks, just one line of code to add and no need to modify QtSingleApplication either.

Comment: Tell anyone who says "don't accept your own answer" to go read the FAQ :)

Comment: Do we need to insert `SetForegroundWindow()` within`QtSingleApplication::activateWindow()` function?

Comment: No, you do not need to modify QtSingleApplication. `QtSingleApplication::activateWindow()` calls `QWidget::activateWindow()` which calls `SetForegroundWindow()` on Windows platforms internally - so it's done for you already. :) See `src\gui\kernel\qwidget_win.cpp:933` of the Qt sources.

Comment: According to [AllowSetForegroundWindow function definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) argument must be *The identifier of the process that will be enabled to set the foreground window. If this parameter is **ASFW_ANY**, all processes will be enabled to set the foreground window.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it reliably with the Qt API alone.

There are multiple solutions for windows. E.g. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/singleinstanceapplication.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166210(VS.80).aspx), and [here](http://www.ucancode.net/CPP_Library_Control_Tool/vc-single-instance-window-createwindow-setwindowpos-setfocus-cwinapp.htm).

The method I've used before is to declare a [shared memory section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx), and write the application's window handle there. Later, when a second instance of your program is started, you can find the window handle of the first and activate it.

I don't think you have the issue of windows preventing you from doing this in this case, because your second instance is the active application, so it is allowed to 'pass focus' to other windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Single Application](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsingleapplication/) in Qt Solutions

> For some applications it is useful or
>   even critical that they are started
>   only once by any user. Future attempts
>   to start the application should
>   activate any already running instance,
>   and possibly perform requested
>   actions, e.g. loading a file, in that
>   instance.

Comment: I'm using Single Application from Qt Solutions; I need to extend it so it always brings the window to the foreground.

Comment: ... // check if app running
    DApplication app( "ProductinternalName", argc, argv);
    if ( app.isRunning() )
    {
        app.sendMessage( QString::null );
        return 0;
    }
... // set activation window
app.setActivationWindow( &w );

... // You may also need to customize how to activate window by
void DApplication::activateWindow()
{
    if ( activationWindow() && !activationWindow()->isVisible() )
    {
        activationWindow()->setVisible( true );
    }
    super::activateWindow();
}

Comment: I'm sorry that code can not be well formatted in comment field.

Answer (score -2):

you can set the setWindowOpacity from 0 to 1 .the only thing is you may open it all the time

Comment: Be more descriptive in your answers. Where do you make this setting? what would the code look like?